How to convert mm to px, rem or em in html page
I know this is a recurring issue and perhaps there is no solution, I've seen other posts here and they didn't solve my problem. But I need to make an HTML page that has 2 inputs (height and width) and below there is a rectangle that will be the same as the measurement given above, but the user has entered the measurements in millimeters and I am unable to convert these values ​​to px, rem or em (it doesn't matter what), in fact I can do it on my monitor but when I change PC it doesn't work. Any idea ?
I'm building the page in html and javascript only.
I already tried to get the monitor size but using the window.innerHtml or outerHTML method it didn't work.

You would somehow have to know the actual physical size of the pixels on your screen to be able to calculate this in metrics. Unless you're expecting people to measure something with their screen, why would you need this?

You have to scale based on screen size and JavaScript best does this. On window resize you can adjust the scaling and elements accordingly.

In this case, the page is for printing labels, and this is to set the size of the label. Therefore, I need her to enter the value in millimeters and I must be able to convert it into px, rem or em so that the label is the correct size and is printed with the desired dimensions.

How i can do this @BGPHiJACK ?

You can use window.innerWidth to help find scaling factor. Imagine you divide such by 100 and then say buffer that to be like 1CM; you can then size all items by PX to represent this scale up by a multiple; say you want main object 5CM it'd be 5 * scaleFactor. Now all you need to figure out is the factor, you may need to adjust from there.

It's not easy with all the math but it's very possible, you may want reference items that are exactly 1CM, exactly 1MM, 1INCH, 1FT  and go from there.

Ah I see. Then I wouldn't bother with how correct it looks on the screen, but just apply the width and height in their correct unit as CSS: width: 30mm;. Then rely on your hardware to print it in the appropriate size on paper. If you know the paper size, then you can at least visually have the ratio's all in order.

So, let's say your label is 40x100mm. Then you can translate that to, for example, 40x100px. Now your client sets the logo size to 20x20mm. That means it's 20x20px on screen with this 1:1 ratio. Now let's zoom 2x into the label. Everything has now doubled in the amount of pixels used, but the logo size is still 20x20mm, it only represented as 40x40px on a 80x200px label with a 1:2 ratio. It means that you don't need to render the actual size of the label, just a representation of it, and that you don't need to convert these units to metrics.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
